# How to get feature id for particular feature after feature ismodify in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2

I am using modify control in OpenLayers 2.12. After feature is modified I am running the function below:

```
building.events.register('afterfeaturemodified',building, onchanges);
```

Where building is my WFS layer. Now in "**onchanges**" function runs and now I want my WFS feature id/name, etc.

My function is as follows:

```
function onchanges(ev)
        {
            var polygonch=ev.feature.geometry;
        }
```

Now in this function I want feature id/name on which modification is done. Or other method to get feature info on which editing/modification is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to call for the feature id, the same way you would for the feature geometry:

```
 changed_polygon_id = ev.feature.id;
```